# SQL Pivot table with updating values

Tags: sql, oracle11g, pivot

I'm working with a list of attributes that change over time but retains versions, so here's a rough idea of what we're looking at (with ID being the primary key):

```
ID  ATTRIBUTENAME    ATTRIBUTEVALUE                  CREATED             MODIFIED            AttributeID
--- ---------------- ------------------------------- ------------------  ------------------- ---
100 DocName          Updated Document                10-JUL-15 08.40.12  10-JUL-15 08.40.12  06
100 Category         Regulatory                      10-JUL-15 08.40.12  10-JUL-15 08.40.12  05
100 Owner            Jane Doe                        10-JUL-15 08.40.12  10-JUL-15 08.40.12  04
100 DocName          Test Document                   10-JUL-15 08.40.12  10-JUL-15 01.10.30  03
100 Category         Regulatory                      10-JUL-15 08.40.12  10-JUL-15 01.10.30  02
100 Owner            John Doe                        10-JUL-15 08.40.12  10-JUL-15 01.10.30  01
```

I want to do a pivot on DocName, Category, and Owner, but only select the most recent AttributeValue where Modified is max. ID is the primary lookup for that list of attributes. AttributeID is a unique GUID (changed to int) for that row in the database.

How would I create a pivot table in this format?

```
ID   DocName          Category   Owner
---  ---------------- ---------- --------
100  Updated Document Regulatory Jane Doe
```

There's hundreds of other attribute names that I will need to add eventually, but this is a concise example. I'm also open to faster/better ideas for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to use conditional aggregation with `rank()`:

```
select id, 
    max(case when attributename = 'DocName' then attributevalue end) docname,
    max(case when attributename = 'Category' then attributevalue end) Category,
    max(case when attributename = 'Owner' then attributevalue end) Owner
from (
    select *, rank() over (partition by id order by modified desc) rn
    from yourtable ) t
where rn = 1
group by id
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work with Oracle 11g with PL/SQL. I'm getting an error about the FROM statement not being in the expected place after the "SELECT *," before Rank().

Comment: Figured it out -- it doesn't like the select * but that's fine -- I only need a handful of columns and not everything anyway. Cheers!